# JQuery - Find values of elements based on other relative elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to find the value of an element (input element) based on a nearby element, specifically in my example I'm looking to return 'Complete' based on it being next to the 'Contract Review Status' field. I cannot use any unique identifier, as my source system will randomise the unique identifier.

```
<td class=" FieldLabel ml-FldLbl ml-BrdRight lo_51395 ml-BrdBottom" style="width:15%;">
    <span id="loitem51395">
        <img id="22508requiredImg" class="required-icon" src="/BackgroundImageGenerator.axd?className=Bullet&amp;classProperties=bulletShape:RequiredIndicatorWidget;baseColor:%23B80000" alt="Required" style="display:none;">
            Contract Review Status:
    </span>
</td>
<td class="ml-FldCnt lo_51395 ml-BrdBottom" style="width:35%;">
    <div id="master_DefaultContent_rts_s8307_f22508c" class="ArcherTreeView DisabledTree">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
            <li id="" class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
                <div class="rtMid">
                    <div data-valueslistvalueid="81019" style="color:#000000;">
                    <input name="master$DefaultContent$rts$s8307$ctl10" type="hidden" class="readOnly" value="81019">
                        Complete
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

I'll be looking to store the 'Complete' in a variable so that I can display conditional graphics, depending on the current status.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no input shown with value `"Complete"`. Question is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you can find the "Contract Review Status", I'd suggest you go up from there to the parentNode's in turn until you find the first td (check jQuery's "closest" method). From there take the next td (check jQuery's "next" method) and down until you find your input element (check jQuery's "find" method).

I hope this is enough information to help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

select the column based on the type of the input type;

```
$('tr > td').find('input[type=hidden]').val()
```

Hope this helps